# SQL-SERVER Filter By ROW_NUMBER and Another Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have this SQL-SERVER Query:**

```
SELECT t.Id,
       t.ClientTemplateFieldId,
       t.ClientTemplateFieldOptionId,
       t.TextData,
       t.NumberData,
       t.DateTimeData,
       t.TreatmentDate,
       t.rn  FROM 
(
 SELECT  tfd.Id,
         tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId,
         tfd.ClientTemplateFieldOptionId,
         tfd.TextData,
         tfd.NumberData,
         tfd.DateTimeData,
         t.TreatmentDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId ORDER BY t.TreatmentDate DESC) as rn 
FROM TemplateFieldData tfd 
     INNER JOIN 
     Treatment t ON tfd.TreatmentId = t.Id
WHERE tfd.IsDeleted = 0 AND
      t.IsDeleted = 0 AND
      tfd.ClientId = 2 AND 
      t.ClientId = 2 AND 
      t.PatientId = 6003720 AND 
      tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId IN
     (1873,1874,1875,1876) 
) AS t

--WHERE CLAUSE...
```

**And this is the table result of the above query:**

```
Id      ClientTemplateFieldId ClientTemplateFieldOptionId TextData NumberData   DateTimeData TreatmentDate              rn
4324    1873                  1627                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    1
4325    1873                  1628                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    2
4326    1873                  1631                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    3
4322    1873                  1627                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-13 09:00:00.000    4
4323    1873                  1629                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-13 09:00:00.000    5
4320    1873                  1626                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-12 22:00:00.000    6
4321    1873                  1630                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-12 22:00:00.000    7
4338    1874                  NULL                        SomeTxt  NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    1
4330    1874                  NULL                        SomeTxt  NULL         NULL         2021-01-13 09:00:00.000    2
4327    1874                  NULL                        SomeTxt  NULL         NULL         2021-01-12 22:00:00.000    3
4328    1875                  NULL                        NULL     10.00        NULL         2021-01-12 22:00:00.000    1
4331    1876                  1634                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-13 09:00:00.000    1
4329    1876                  1632                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-12 22:00:00.000    2
```

What should I put in the Where Clause in order to retrieve all rows with row_number = 1 and
also if there is a row with the same TreatmentDate and ClientTemplateFieldId as of one of the rows where
row_number = 1, I need that row to.

**Meaning I need this result:**

```
Id      ClientTemplateFieldId ClientTemplateFieldOptionId TextData NumberData   DateTimeData TreatmentDate              rn
4324    1873                  1627                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    1
4325    1873                  1628                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    2
4326    1873                  1631                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    3
4338    1874                  NULL                        SomeTxt  NULL         NULL         2021-01-14 09:00:00.000    1
4328    1875                  NULL                        NULL     10.00        NULL         2021-01-12 22:00:00.000    1
4331    1876                  1634                        NULL     NULL         NULL         2021-01-13 09:00:00.000    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `MAX()` window function instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` to get all the rows with the latest `TreatmentDate` for each `ClientTemplateFieldId`:

```
SELECT t.Id,
       t.ClientTemplateFieldId,
       t.ClientTemplateFieldOptionId,
       t.TextData,
       t.NumberData,
       t.DateTimeData,
       t.TreatmentDate,
       t.rn  
FROM (
 SELECT  tfd.Id,
         tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId,
         tfd.ClientTemplateFieldOptionId,
         tfd.TextData,
         tfd.NumberData,
         tfd.DateTimeData,
         t.TreatmentDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId ORDER BY t.TreatmentDate DESC) AS rn, 
         MAX(t.TreatmentDate) OVER (PARTITION BY tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId) AS max_TreatmentDate
 FROM TemplateFieldData tfd 
     INNER JOIN 
     Treatment t ON tfd.TreatmentId = t.Id
 WHERE tfd.IsDeleted = 0 AND
      t.IsDeleted = 0 AND
      tfd.ClientId = 2 AND 
      t.ClientId = 2 AND 
      t.PatientId = 6003720 AND 
      tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId IN
     (1873,1874,1875,1876) 
) AS t  
WHERE t.TreatmentDate = t.max_TreatmentDate
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` is not actually needed but I kept it in my query just in case you want it in the results.

Comment: Wonderful works good. Is this query have efficient coast because that addition of MAX()?

Comment: For this requirement you don't need ROW_NUMBER(), so remove it and use only MAX(). It is a window function so it usually performs better than any other way.

Comment: you mean to stay only with this row: 
 MAX(t.TreatmentDate) OVER (PARTITION BY tfd.ClientTemplateFieldId) AS max_TreatmentDate ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need the column rn in the results.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that this entire query result (without the where condition) is created as a View called T for example, you can do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE T.rn = 1
OR EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM T as T2 
    WHERE T2.TreatmentDate = T.TreatmentDate 
    AND T2.ClientTemplateFieldId = T.ClientTemplateFieldId 
    AND T.rn != 1 
    AND T2.rn = 1)
```

Comment: I get an error when trying this query: "Invalid Object name T" (on the 'T' in the sub query you wrote)

Comment: That's why you need to first create a View in your DB as I mentioned else you need to repeat the same entire statement twice, which is not pleasing. T represents the entire Select statement that you have. Did you create the view? Check this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp